# How to reset statistics after UPDATE STATISTICS ... WITH ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, index-statistics

For query tuning and testing purposes, you can manually assign a rowcount and pagecount to a table's index statistics by running `UPDATE STATISTICS`. But how do you recompute/reset the statistics to the table's actual contents?

```
--- Create a table..
CREATE TABLE dbo.StatTest (
    i      int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_StatTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (i)
);
GO

--- .. and give it a thousand-or-so rows:
DECLARE @i int=1;
INSERT INTO dbo.StatTest (i) VALUES (@i);

WHILE (@i<1000) BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO dbo.StatTest (i) SELECT @i+i FROM dbo.StatTest;
    SET @i=@i*2;
END;
```

A dummy query:

```
SELECT i%100, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.StatTest GROUP BY i%100;
```

... will return the following query plan (the row estimate in the Index Scan is 1024 rows).

[image: 10 000 rows]

Run the `UPDATE STATISTICS` command..

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.StatTest WITH ROWCOUNT=10000000;
```

... and the plan looks like this, now with an estimate of 10 million rows:

[image: 10 million rows]

How do I reset the rowcount to the actual contents of the table without using `WITH ROWCOUNT`?

I've tried `WITH FULLSCAN`, `WITH RESAMPLE` and `WITH SAMPLE n ROWS`, but the statistics rowcount remains 10 million rows. Inserting a row or even deleting all of the rows doesn't update the statistics, because the change is too small.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` with the `COUNT_ROWS` option.

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE 
(   { database_name | database_id | 0 } 
    [ , { table_name | table_id | view_name | view_id } 
    [ , { index_name | index_id } ] ] 
) [ WITH [ NO_INFOMSGS ] [ , ] [ COUNT_ROWS ] ]
```

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188414.aspx)